# xhprof not working wamp 2.2

Tags: installation, wamp, php-5.3, xhprof

I have downloaded the dll file from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/xhprof/0.10.6/ and kept the first 32 bit file at C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext and also include it in my php.ini file (as extension=php_xhprof.dll). But when I call phpinfo() xhprof is now showing. I am not getting any errors in my log.

Comment: Did you try to restart your webserver?

Comment: yes, I did. I am installing on my local wamp but still not getting it

Comment: Any errors in your apache log? Are you sure you need the 32-bit version?

Comment: yes I am using 32 bit windows 7

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 `php.ini` file and you may have edited the wrong one.

To make sure you edit the correct `php.ini` file i.e. the one used by Apache use the wampmanager menus like so:

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Check this has the new `extension` and if not add it to this file.

The `php.ini` file in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` is only used when you are running PHP CLI i.e. running PHP from the Command Line

Also make sure you downloaded the Thread Safe version of `xhprof` that will be the ones with `-ts-` in the zip file name.

Also the `vc9` or `vc11` should match the compiler used to compile your Apache and PHP. If you are using PHP5.3 (very old) then you had better hope it is `VC9` but it is quite possible that your Apache/PHP may have been compiled with `VC6` which means this extension will not run with your version of Apache/PHP.

Comment: Did you use the vc9 versions of the dll's